# C - Why when i compile it don't recognize the source file (.c)?

Tags: c, include

I have a task to do and it is to implement some interfaces, but when i include the head file it write for me that it don't recognize the methods

I mean i have a classes

```
A.h
{
    some code....
}
A.c
{
   #include "A.h" 
   implemented methods...
}
```

and if i have a class B and i want to use the A class if i include the **.h** file it don't work
Like this:

```
B.c
{
   #include "A.h"
}
```

but if i include the **A.c** it do recognize the methods, do anybody have any idea why is that?

Comment: Classes? Methods? I thought you talk about C?

Comment: nevertheless, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful.

Comment: Also, you should not `#include "A.c"`. You compile all the required `.c` files & then link them together. Your compiler would do it for you; check unwind's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is rather ... strange, but I think you're having a linking issue.

If you have code in "A.c", that gets compiled into an object file ("A.o" or "A.obj", typically) that holds the resulting code.

But just because you say `#include "A.h"` in a different C file ("B.c"), that does *not* magically cause the "A.o" object file to be linked in.

Compile with something like:

```
$ cc -o myprogram B.c A.c
```

to make the compiler combine both C files into a single executable, or perhaps

```
$ cc -o myprogram B.c a.o
```

to link with the pre-existing object file.

Also, there are no "methods" in C, and your braces are very strange.